# How do I save something in a batch program that loads on next use?

Tags: batch-file

I'm using Batch to create a kind of 'AI' program. It's pretty basic and i'm fine with that, but is there anyway to make it so if I open up the program and tell it to save something (text)? Then have it load up when i type in a certain thing next time i start the program?

Comment: Sure, you can save something with `echo text > file.txt`.  And read it back by piping it through another programme, or by reading it into an environment variable: [How can I load the contents of a text file into a batch file variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134001/how-can-i-load-the-contents-of-a-text-file-into-a-batch-file-variable)  I think you need a more specific question if you want more than a vague answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well not sure if this is what you want... 'cause you don't specify if want "Human AI" or a AI for other kind of bot-Task.

This is only a examples that I wrote in few minutes but maybe this can help you to start:

```
@Echo off

:Ask
Echo+
SET /P "Question=>>[YOU] "
Call :Answer "%Question%"
GOTO:ASK

:Answer
Echo+
For /F "Usebackq Tokens=1,* Delims=;" %%A in ("AI.txt") Do (
    For %%@ in (%Question%) DO (
        Echo "%%A"| FINDSTR /I "\"%%@\"" 1>NUL && (
            Echo:   [AI] %%B
            GOTO:ASK
        )
    )
)
Echo:   [AI] I don't understand you.
GOTO:EOF
```

[image]

**AI.txt content:**

```
matrix;Don't talk about it if you don't awake... 
pennys;You said pennys? That remembered me I'm so hungry... ;)  
dog;I like it!
name;My name is Bachitia, yes it's cool...
```

> PART 2

This is another kind of AI...

```
@Echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set /A "INDEX=1"

REM :Check_Question {INDEX} {Response if answer is not saved} {Response if answer is saved}

Call :Check_Question "_%INDEX%" "Hello, I'm glad to meet you, What's your name? " "Welcome again {Value}"
Call :Check_Question "_%INDEX%" "What are your hobbies? " "Are you {Value} again? "

Pause&Exit

:Check_Question
If not exist "AI.txt" (Echo _0;DUMMY>"AI.txt")
For /F "Usebackq Tokens=1,* Delims=;" %%A in ("AI.txt") Do (
    If "%%A" EQU "%~1" (
        Set "Answer=%~3"
        Set "Answer=!Answer:{Value}=%%B!"
        Echo !Answer!
        Set /A "INDEX+=1"
        Exit /B 0
    )
)
Set /P "Question=%~2"
Echo _%INDEX%;%Question%>>"AI.txt"
Set /A "INDEX+=1"
Exit /B 0
```

**First run:**

[image]

**Ai.txt auto generated content:**

```
_0;DUMMY
_1;Elektro
_2;programming
```

**Second run:**

[image]

Comment: I think you went a little above and beyond the call of duty there. All he wants to know is how to create constant variables. Nonetheless, +1