# How can I read a comma delimited text file in a Windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have the next file txt with only one line:

1,2,3,4,5, 6,..., n

I need to capture all the numbers that are separated by commas.

Comment: This might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134001/how-can-i-load-the-contents-of-a-text-file-into-a-batch-file-variable

Comment: Yes, but it is with a fixed file

Comment: In my case the number of "numbers" may vary

Comment: You need to be more specific as to what you mean by "capture". What exactly do you want to do with the numbers? Store them in an array? Print them, one per line? ...

Comment: Yes, print them, one per line.

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /P "numbers="<csvfile

for %%I in (%numbers%) do (
    echo %%I
)
```

The `for` command without switches uses commas, semicolons, spaces, and tabs as delimiters.  In the example above, `%%I` will be each number in turn from left to right.

Comment: `+1` This works as long as the line length does not exceed 1021 bytes. You could read the line using FOR /F instead, but then the line lengh limit is increased to a bit less than 8191 bytes.

Comment: Just to clarify, dbenham is talking about the `set /P "numbers="<csvfile` line being limited to 1021 bytes.  The alternative is `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("csvfile") do set "numbers=%%~I"`.  The second `for` loop is still needed to split the `%numbers%` variable into an unknown number of entities.

Comment: @dbenham - you have found a workaround about `+1`  :-)

Comment: @npocmaka - Yea, I saw that on a comment somewhere, I think in meta. We'll have to wait to see how long it takes for that to be banned as well.

Comment: @dbenham ＋1 way to stick it to the man.  (I also tried &#x2b;1 but comments apparently don't allow HTML entities.)

Answer (score 3):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem Variable to hold digits while reading numbers
    set "number="
    rem Variable to hold the table index where data is captured
    set "n=0"

    rem Decompose input file in characters and filter
    for /f %%a in ('
        cmd /q /u /c "type numbers.txt&echo(," ^| more ^| findstr /r /x /c:"[0-9,]"
    ') do if "%%a"=="," (
        rem If a comma is found, capture current number
        if defined number set /a "numbers[!n!]=!number!", "n+=1"
        set "number="
    ) else (
        rem If it is not a comma, is a number to concatenate to current one
        set "number=!number!%%a"
    )

    rem Show numbers captured
    set numbers[
```

This will "capture" each value into the elements of an array. As the full data has to be loaded by `for` command into memory, and each valid character in input file will include a CRLF ending, the limit in input line is 715 MB approx.

Comment: `+1` I frequently forget about that unicode trick. This works well, though it is quite slow if dealing with a large data set.

Answer (score 3):

rojo shows a good solution for relatively small data sets.

MC ND shows a good pure batch solution for large data sets, except it can become quite slow.

A good fast solution for large data sets requires using something other than pure batch. One option is my [JREPL.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044), a hybrid JScript/batch script that performs regular expression replacements on text.

Assuming JREPL.BAT is somewhere in your PATH, and your csv is "test.csv", then the following will print out each number, one per line:

```
jrepl "," "\n" /x /f "test.csv"
```

Since JREPL is a batch script, you must use `CALL JREPL` if you want to use it within another batch script.

The following shows how to store the numbers in an "array" of variables, using FINDSTR to establish the array index. Note that I do not need `call jrepl` because jrepl is used within a FOR IN('') clause:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Store the numbers in an array
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%A in (
  'jrepl "," "\n" /x /f "test.csv" ^| findstr /n "^"'
) do (
  set "n[%%A]=%%B"
  set "n.count=%%A"
)

:: Display the numbers
for /l %%N in (1 1 %n.count%) do echo !n[%%N]!
```

Or you could use JREPL to parse out the numbers and establish the index values. This takes a bit more code, but it is more efficient:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Store the numbers in an array
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%A in (
  'jrepl "\d+" "(n+=1)+':'+$0" /jmatch /jbeg "var n=0" /f "test.csv"'
) do (
  set "n[%%A]=%%B"
  set "n.count=%%A"
)

:: Display the numbers
for /l %%N in (1 1 %n.count%) do echo !n[%%N]!
```